# Nested Table needs to be separated by columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

1. I have a nested table and I have tried to unnest it. I have used the following code to do it:

```
SELECT purchaseId
    , CAST (PURCHASECREATED AS DATE) AS SALE_DT
    
    , (SELECT ARRAY_AGG (DISTINCT UPPER (DISCOUNTTYPE) IGNORE NULLS) FROM 
           UNNEST(PURCHASEDISCOUNTS)) AS DISCOUNT_TYPE
    
    , (SELECT ARRAY_AGG (DISTINCT UPPER (DISCOUNTCODE) IGNORE NULLS) FROM 
           UNNEST(PURCHASEDISCOUNTS)) AS DISCOUNT_CODE
    
    , UPPER (g.DISCOUNTTYPE) AS DISCOUNT_SALESSYSTEM

FROM `TABLE 
    , UNNEST(PURCHASELINEITEMS) f
    , UNNEST(ITEMDISCOUNTS) g
```

2. I get the following results:

As you can see the SALE_DT and DISCOUNT_SALESSYSTEM have blank rows. I would like each row to be unique.

| SALE_DT | DISCOUNT_TYPE | DISCOUNT_CODE | DISCOUNT_SALES_SYSTEM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-04 | EMPLOYEE | 9876 | EMPLOYEEDISCOUNT1 |
|  | SUBSCRIPTION | 1234 |  |

3. How can I separated the nested columns so they look like this:

| SALE_DT | DISCOUNT_TYPE_1 | DISCOUNT_TYPE_2 | DISCOUNT_SALES_SYSTEM | DISCOUNT_CODE_1 | DISCOUNT_CODE_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-04 | EMPLOYEE | SUBSCRIPTION | EMPLOYEEDISCOUNT1 | 9876 | 1234 |

Comment: both `discount_type` and `discount_code` array has same number of elements in it ? and the elements with same position in both array should be paired together ? I mean `employee` should have `9876` discount code only, not `1234` ?

Comment: No the elements can vary. i.e it could be "Employee", "Subscription", or "Other." Both entries are important "9876" and "1234"